# jstree get data as treeLike array

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

Say you have the following type of data:

```
{
    children: [{id: 1}, {id:2}, {id:3}],
    id: 85,
    text: "myParent
}
```

Now using jstree i would like to get this data out so tha the selected nodes will give me a result like this:

```
    result = [{id: 85, text: 'myParent', children: [{id: 1}]}]
```

In the above case i have selected `node` 1

Basically it gives me the parent and then the selected children in a sub array.

so far i have attempted with the following:

```
$('#dataTree').on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
    $('#dataTree').jstree(true).get_json('#', {flat:false})
})
```

However the above code does not return only for the selected nodes

So my question to you guys is how would i go around doing this?

Comment: How is it going? Did you solve your  problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify selected node instead of using `#` which is the root.

So you could do it like below. Also check demo - [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/3fr1vyLg/).

```
.on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
    var result = data.selected.map(function(node){
        return $('#dataTree').jstree(true).get_json(node, {flat:false});
    });
    // ... do something with result array
});
```